# Getting the year of the current date

Tags: datetime, delphi

```
if StrToInt(sY) > 2013 then
begin
  bDate := False;
  ShowMessage('Year is bigger than current year');
  Exit;
end;
```

This is what I have at this stage but I'm pretty sure there is a way to get the current year instead of having to manually type it in delphi code, would be much appreciated if someone could help me with the code for it.

Comment: Have you found the documentation yet? And the source code for DateUtils?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[`DateUtils.YearOf(Now)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.DateUtils.YearOf) will get you the current year,

or use

[`SysUtils.CurrentYear`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.SysUtils.CurrentYear).

As @Remy points out, [`Date`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.SysUtils.Date) is more to the point than `Now`. So is [`DateUtils.Today`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.DateUtils.Today).

Comment: I would use `Date()` instead of `Now()` since the time is not needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm reasonably sure that the year never changes during the course of a day!

Comment: I am aware of that. The point was to avoid the overhead of encoding the time portion of the returned `TDateTime` when it is not going to be used.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, it will burn the processor. (joking!)